# "SSL decryption failed" error when running "npx create-react-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, npm

I was going to learn react but when I tried to create the app using the following command:

```
npx create-react-app news-app
```

It gave me the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss:         
11920:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record 
mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashutosh PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05- 
08T08_16_48_558Z-debug-0.log
```

I cannot understand the error, I even opened the log file but same with this, I can't understand...

[Link to the file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18kiJRb9Eax5Ufwxnm1JtB_QyhS5QAMiuim0fZi8j9z8/edit?usp=sharing)

My whole console output/error:

```
Creating a new React app in E:\programming\react js\news-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/postcss: 
11920:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record 
mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashutosh PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05- 
08T08_16_48_558Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react- 
scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting news-app/ from E:\programming\react js
Done.
```

Comment: i got the same issue while developing angular, it looks like this is an issue with npm itself!

Comment: @Ashutosh Kumar have you found any solution?